# Change google maps marker icon when external link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map with lots of markers on it (gathered from MySQL database). I'm currently using the following code to change a marker's icon when that marker is clicked:

```
var redbikeicon = "images/bike_red.png";

<?php
    $result=mysql_query("select * from sites") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['Latitude']; ?>, <?php echo $row['Longitude']; ?>),
        map: map, icon: bikeicon});

        //add event to every marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            //change icon color
            this.setIcon(redbikeicon);      //replace default icon with red version (color-marking all chosen markers)

        })
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

This code works fine, but I now need to make the same thing happen when a link on the page is clicked - there is a list of links on the page next to the map, and each one corresponds to one of the markers on the map. When a link is clicked, the corresponding marker should change colors just like it does when the marker itself is clicked. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You need a way to relate the link to the individual markers.  Have you thought of a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have enough experience with this to figure it out. From the answers below I see that a marker ID can be defined, so I'm working on that now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do something similar, except I use a hover. I changed it to a click for you below. I am using jQuery for this as well. Anyway, you set up you click event on the link. The link has an attribute called "record_id" which corresponds to a property you set for your marker, also called "record_id".

When the link is clicked, you grab the id, and then iterate through all of your markers until you find the one that matches, and then you change the icon using the setIcon method provided in the googlemaps api.

hope that helps.

setting the id:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    record_id: record_id,
    position: point,
    map: map,
    title: name,
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=whatever|BDD73C|000000'
});
```

setting your action on the anchor:

```
$("a.whatever").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    changeMarker(id);                             
});
```

using setIcon to swap ut the icon for one of a different color:

```
function changeMarker(record_id){
    for (i in Markers){
        if(Markers[i].record_id == record_id){
            Markers[i].setIcon('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=title|EC2A8C|000000');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, hook me up with a little +1 if it works. I'm trying to get to 1000. Lol. Thanks. If you have any questions, let me know, but I think it is all there. The only part that bugs me is the iteration through all the markers. If there are a ton, it could take a while. There must be some way to search a javascript object using a property value, that would be a good upgrade.

Comment: I'm getting 'Markers is not defined' when the links are clicked. I assume Markers should be a global array of markers? So I should just do something like Markers[i]=marker for each marker I set up?

Comment: yeah, Start with a global Markers array, var Markers = []; Then after you make each marker, push it into Markers, like Markers.push(marker);

Comment: can you provide also the `HTML` codes? I'm not familiar with setting the action to anchor and the record_id. I search but i can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Trigger the 'click' event on the marker when the link is clicked.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
```

[example with a clickable dynamic sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html) (the click listener opens an infowindow)