# How to select marker by coordinates or title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have map with dynamically generated markers using [gmaps.js](https://github.com/HPNeo/gmaps)
And it works.

But I would like to select marker by coordinates and trigger click on it.

I know how to trigger it but I can't figure out how to proper select marker in jQuery or find it in map.markers array?

This is my code:

```
# = require lib/gmaps
$(document).on 'ready', ->

  if $('#map').length > 0
    map = new GMaps(
      div: "#map"
      lat: 53.5500000
      lng: 10.0000000
      zoom: 12
    )

    url = "nearby_cardiologists.json" + window.location.search
    $.getJSON url, (data) ->
      if data and data.length > 0
        firstMarker = data[0]
        map.setCenter firstMarker.latitude, firstMarker.longitude

        $.each data, (index, cardiologist) ->
          cardiologist_info = '<p>' + '<b>' + cardiologist.title + ' ' + cardiologist.first_name + ' ' + cardiologist.last_name + '</b><br>' + cardiologist.street + ', ' + cardiologist.city
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(content: cardiologist_info)
          marker = map.addMarker
            lat: cardiologist.latitude
            lng: cardiologist.longitude
          google.maps.event.addListener marker, "click", ->
            infowindow.open map, this

        $("#nearby_cardiologists").on 'click', 'a', (event) ->
          event.preventDefault()
          cardiologist = $(this)
          i = cardiologist.data('id')
          marker = map.markers[0]
          map.setCenter cardiologist.data('coordinates').latitude, cardiologist.data('coordinates').longitude
          map.setZoom 16

      else
        $('#map').hide()
```

My goal is to click on link and zoom + show info window by opening it or triggering click on marker

Comment: It'd help if you showed us some of your code... to do what you're trying you'd probably need your own array of markers, which you could then loop through, comparing each marker's lat/lng with the lat/lng coordinates you're searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answer should help you with this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524925/1856970

You need to be able to tie the marker to the a link in some way (this example uses an id attribute appended to both to determine the correct marker click event to trigger), in order to be able to find it at runtime. It is not possible to slect the marker solely by it's long/lat coords.

An alternative method would be to create the a link click events within the foreach loop in which you instantiate markers. This simplifies things by allowing you to have each marker in scope as you progress and eliminates the need for you to select the markers at a later execution point.

Once you have the appropriate marker, getting the long lat is trivial and can be done using [getPosition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Marker) (presumably to center the map etc).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little or show me an example about alternative way?

Comment: The link provided is a useable example of how to achieve this, I'll have a scout around for a few more.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out :)